# Trigger causing NullPointerException only through Data Loader

Tags: trigger, data-loader, null-pointer, before-trigger

I've developed a trigger to run if an Account owner changes, and based on the profile of who it changes to, update upcoming events titled "Welcome Call" to match the account owner. This runs fine for individual updates but in data load jobs I'm getting the following error for any Account with a Welcome Call event:

```
accOwnerWelcomeCallUpdate: execution of BeforeUpdate
caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
Trigger.accOwnerWelcomeCallUpdate: line 10, column 1
```

Trigger code:

```
trigger accOwnerWelcomeCallUpdate on Account (before update) {

    Map<id,user> mpuser=new Map<id,user>([select id, name, profile.name from user where id =:trigger.new[0].OwnerId]);

    for(Account newAcc: trigger.newMap.Values()){

        String newOwnerProfile;

        // Get owner profile name
        if (mpuser.get(trigger.newMap.get(newAcc.id).ownerid).profile.name != NULL) {
            newOwnerProfile = (mpuser.get(trigger.newMap.get(newAcc.id).ownerid).profile.name).trim(); //<-- NullPointerException
        }
        System.Debug('NewOwnerProfile found: ' + newOwnerProfile);
        // Check if account owner has changed and is a Champion or Edvisor, and has welcome calls
        if (trigger.old[0].OwnerId != trigger.new[0].OwnerId && 
            (newOwnerProfile == 'Acquire Career Champion' || newOwnerProfile == 'Eddi Edvisor')) {

                System.Debug('Change of owner detected');
                // Get Welcome Call events and reassign to new Account owner
                List<Event> welcomeCalls = [SELECT Id, AccountId, OwnerId, StartDateTime, Subject FROM Event WHERE AccountId =: trigger.old[0].Id AND Subject LIKE '%Welcome Call Booking%'];
                System.Debug('Number of welcome calls found: ' + welcomeCalls.size());
                for (Event wc : welcomeCalls) {
                    if (wc.OwnerId != trigger.new[0].OwnerId && wc.StartDateTime >= System.now()) {
                    wc.OwnerId = trigger.new[0].OwnerId;
                    System.Debug('Welcome call assigned to new account owner');
                }
            }

            update welcomeCalls;

            } else {System.Debug('No change to Champ or Edvisor or welcome call found.');}
    }

}
```

Anyone know of a reason this would be finding a null value in bulk processing but not in individual updates?

Cheers

Comment: Any chance the Owner of the account is a queue?I suggest you use `mapName.containsKey()` to check if the value is present in the map or not

Comment: Also your code isn't bulkified, move the SOQL and DML statements out of the for Loop..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On line 3, you only query users which are owner of the first account triggered.

```
[select id, name, profile.name from user where id =:trigger.new[0].OwnerId]
```

I guess that's why it only works for individual update, and not when updating more with Data loader. Accounts probably have differents owner, so

```
mpuser.get(trigger.newMap.get(newAcc.id).ownerid)
```

probably returns null.

Your query at line 3 should fetch all users who own a triggered account.